# traverse a list (SortedTree) with public String()

Tags: java, tree, traversal

How do I traverse a SortedTree list with a public String method?

I'm trying to write a method that determined the next item in the list, sets cursor to null, an returns the item. I then set the cursor to null and return null. Ideally, I'd like to append to a string (like toString), and then select an entry that follows the one matching cursor. (If there is an entry).

Or would I be better off using something like an ArrayList?

My tree driver:

```
SortedTree tree = new SortedTree();

    // Populate the tree
    tree.add("Jim");
    tree.add("John");
    tree.add("Henry");
    tree.add("Paul");
    tree.add("Ringo");
    tree.add("Mick");
    tree.add("Keith");
    tree.add("Charlie");
    tree.add("Eric");
    tree.add("David");
    tree.add("George");

//         traverse it looking for eeeeerie names
    System.out.println("Eeeeerie items in our tree:");
    String item = tree.first();
    while (item != null) {
        if (item.contains("e") || item.contains("E"))
            System.out.println(item);
        item = tree.next();
    }
```

Here is the method I'm trying to make to return the appropriate names.
As it stands, my method is only returning the name "Charlie", but the output should be:

"Eeeeerie items in our tree:
Charlie
Eric
George
Henry
Keith"

```
public String next() {
    cursor = root;
    String nodeList = null;
    while (cursor.right != null) {
        cursor = cursor.right;
        nodeList += cursor.item;
    }

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I should also include my code for the cursor:

```
TreeNode cursor; // node to remember the current traversal position

public void setCursor(TreeNode node) {

    this.cursor = node;
}
```

Here is my first() method which is called in the driver

```
public String first() {
    TreeNode beginning = root;
    do {
        beginning = beginning.left;
    } while (beginning.left != null);
    setCursor(beginning);
    return beginning.item;
}
```

Comment: This is unclear.  It looks (from the fact that you have given us the code for its methods) like `SortedTree` is a class you are writing.  (Perhaps as an exercise?)  It doesn't appear to be a standard Java class, anyway.  But, assuming you don't *have* to use `SortedTree` (whatever it is), you'd be better off with a `List<String>`.  Use `Collections.sort()` to sort the list first.  Then use `for(String s : myNames) { ... }` to iterate the strings, and pick the ones you want (using your current `if`).

Comment: Or alternatively, collect the ones you want in a new list, and sort that at the end, before writing them out.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure how to exactly do that.  Would that use an array list?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Jim");
// ... add rest here ...

List<String> eerie = new ArrayList<String>(); // a new empty list

// Collect the ones you want
for(String name : names) {
    // I'm not sure what 'contains()' is (in your code), but this will work.
    if(item.indexOf("e") != -1 || item.indexOf("E") != -1) {
        eerie.add(name);
    }
}

// Sort 'em
Collections.sort(eerie);

// Print 'em
for(String name : eerie) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul! Would this all just replace my next() method?

Comment: Err, no.  It would replace everything in your original code sample.  That is, it solves the entire problem you originally described (as in 'but the output should be') without using SortedTree (whatever that is).

Comment: (What is 'SortedTree' anyway?)